# Choosing Optimum Sampling Frequency

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, digital-signal-processing

There was an interesting post made by Jonathan Kinlay where he discusses the use of a Fourier Transform to discover a potentially optimum bar frequency to choose as an input to a trading system.

I am hoping that someone could shed some light on exactly what is being used here to generate the indicator graph as I don't find it completely clear.

Link to post is here:  [Signal Processing and Sample Frequency](http://jonathankinlay.com/index.php/2015/08/signal-processing-sample-frequency-www-jonathankinlay-com/)

I appreciate any info on this.